# Why does CreateDIBSection() fail when the window is offscreen?

Tags: delphi, winapi, graphics, sdl

I'm building a Delphi component to embed an [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org) rendering surface on a VCL form. It works just fine as long as the form is on-screen at the moment that the SDL surface is created.  Otherwise, it's not able to create any rendering textures.

I traced into the SDL code and ended up with the following function call, which fails (returns NULL):

```
data->hbm = CreateDIBSection(renderdata->memory_hdc, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &data->pixels, NULL, 0);
```

The HDC is a valid handle to the drawing context owned by a control that has its own HWND window handle, that's been set up properly.  But when the control is created offscreen, which commonly happens in Delphi, (all forms, with their controls, are created in a hidden state until it's time to display them,) the CreateDIBSection call will fail until the control is actually visible.

Also, if it's created onscreen, then hidden and re-shown (if it's on a tab sheet and I switch tabs, for example,) any textures I create get blanked during this process.

This is driving me nuts. Anyone know what's going on and how I can work around it?

Comment: Just an idea.... Have you watched the window Handle? Isn't it butchered and recreated?

Comment: Nope.  DestroyWnd never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The drawing context is only valid during Paint processing.

Comment: What is "paint processing"? When does it occur?

Comment: "Paint" processing means while in the control's Paint method, which is called by PaintWindow in response to WM_PAINT messages. PaintWindow is what initializes the control's device context handle.

Comment: Do you care to explain your comment? Or are you just into making baseless statements?

Comment: Why do I have to explain fundamentals of an API, it's all documented. You've got it all wrong. A device context is ready to operate on when you retrieve it. It doesn't need to be initialized, the defaults are already set. And there doesn't need to be a WM_PAINT message to operate on it, it's valid as soon as you have the handle. It would take you a minute to retrieve a device context in a button handler and draw on a form surface. Then you'd know all these. And surely you should be able to tell that the API wouldn't care Delphi specific methods which Paint and PaintWindow is.

Comment: So you haven't looked at the source; you're just blathering away... The drawing context handle for control canvases is initialized by Delphi in the WM_PAINT handler and released at the end of processing.

Comment: In other words, if WM_PAINT isn't sent because the control is off-screen the HDC handle doesn't get created.

Thanks for downvoting me without taking two minutes to actually try to understand the explanation.

Comment: I spent more than two minutes. The question says there is a valid HDC. Your answer makes no sense and additional explanation does not fit in. And there is no such thing as a drawing context.